# Rails group errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

I have a very big `Project` model, and I use many tabs to show the different parts of the form.

The idea : each tab regroups a specific subset of the fields for my model, and if there is an error, I would like to highlight the title of the tab in red.

It is very simple for nested associations, because I just have to check for `object.errors[:association].any?`

But for all the other fields, it would be very tedious to do

```
object.errors[:name] or object.errors[:start_date] or object.error[:end_date]...
```

**Is there a way to group some errors together ?** The following should return true if there are errors in either `:name, :start_date`...

```
object.errors[:basic_params].any?
```

In my HTML it looks like this

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#tab-summary" data-toggle="tab">Résumé</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-echanges" data-toggle="tab"
        <%= 'class="text-danger"'.html_safe if @etude.errors[:echanges].any? %>>Echanges</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-params" data-toggle="tab"
        <%= 'class="text-danger"'.html_safe if @etude.errors[:basic_params].any? %>>Paramètres</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-phases" data-toggle="tab"
        <%= 'class="text-danger"'.html_safe if @etude.errors[:phases].any? %>> Phases</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#tab-candidatures" data-toggle="tab"
        <%= 'class="text-danger"'.html_safe if @etude.errors[:competences].any? %>> Candidatures</a>
    </li>
```

I know in the mean time I can do something like this, but I'd really like to have some error grouping system.

```
[:name, :start_date, :end_date].each do |field|
  return true if object.errors.include?(field)
end
```

Comment: You mean like this gem: https://github.com/adzap/grouped_validations?

Comment: Of f***. Yes absolutely. The gem is quite old but I believe it's still working with Rails 4 ? If yes, then you can add a proper answer that I will mark as accepted solution.

Comment: Ouch. According to the issues, it's not compatible with rails 4.1+

Comment: Uff, took me a while, but managed to get it working for rails 4.1+. https://github.com/BroiSatse/grouped_validations. Alternatively you can have a look at reformer gem - it is a part of a new trending architecture in rails called trailblazer. Might be of use to you.

Comment: Forgot to add: branch name `rails_4.1`

Answer (score 1):

I can't match your desired `:[]` lookup syntax precisely, but if this is all you want to do, why not just use a structure like the following?

```
example_params = [:name, :start_date, :end_date]
errors.any? { |e| example_params.include? e }
```